# npm install x509 not working on windows 10

Tags: windows, visual-c++, x509certificate, npm-install

I am facing issue with installing npm module "x509". But getting error. I am using my Angular APP to read some x509 cert for fecthing subject info.

```
           K:\Codes\AWS\REPOS\UI\utilities\configrestui\node_modules\x509>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\n
           odejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
           Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
           C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(54,5): error MSB8020: The build tool
           s for Visual Studio 2012 (Platform Toolset = 'v110') cannot be found. To build using the v110 build tools, please install
           Visual Studio 2012 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Projec
           t menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution". [K:\Codes\AWS\REPOS\UI\utilities\configrestui\
           node_modules\x509\build\x509.vcxproj]
           gyp ERR! build error
           gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
           gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:
           23)
           gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
           gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
           gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
           gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
           gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gy
           p\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
           gyp ERR! cwd K:\Codes\AWS\REPOS\UI\utilities\configrestui\node_modules\x509
           gyp ERR! node -v v6.10.3
           gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
           gyp ERR! not ok
           npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
           npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"}
           (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
           npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\angular-ide\node_modules\chokidar\node_module
           s\fsevents):
           npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"}
           (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
           npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
           npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "instal
           l" "x509" "--save"
           npm ERR! node v6.10.3
           npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
           npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

           npm ERR! x509@0.3.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
           npm ERR! Exit status 1
           npm ERR!
           npm ERR! Failed at the x509@0.3.2 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
           npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
           npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the x509 package,
           npm ERR! not with npm itself.
           npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
           npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
           npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
           npm ERR!     npm bugs x509
           npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
           npm ERR!     npm owner ls x509
           npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

           npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
           npm ERR!     K:\Codes\AWS\REPOS\UI\utilities\configrestui\npm-debug.log
```

I verified my installables, i dont have v110 which is VS 2012 VC ++ redistributables . I installed from MS VS VC++ build tools 2012. but still gettintg same error .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to install VS2012 to make this build.But I tried on ubuntu 16.04 LTS all works well.